# How to completely reinstall ubuntu?

Tags: installation

I really screwed up my computer and I'm pretty sure a clean install is my only option. I used a CD to install it. How to I uninstall and reinstall ubuntu? Acer Aspire 3690

Answer (score 1):

Don't concern yourself with uninstalling, simply boot the CD, read and follow the prompts. If you like, you can use the same disk partitions, or redefine them. To be sure that there's nothing left, elect to "Format" the partitions.

Better luck next time!

You could also boot the CD, select "Try Ubuntu without installing", mount the harddisk, and copy your important data from it to another disk, USB key, or whatever.

Comment: What do you mean by boot the CD? Do I put it in the tray and restart?

Comment: @Drew, yes, just like you did the first time.

Comment: What do I do? It won't boot the CD on the Acer screen and goes straight to ububtu.

Comment: @Drew - you'll have to find a way to get the BIOS to boot the CD, or make a bootable USB.

Comment: @Drew You probably need to update the BIOS' Boot Priority order. Right when you start the computer there should be a splash screen, and it should say which key to press to access the BIOS (usually something like DELETE, ESC, F11 or F7). In BIOS, look for something like "Boot Priority" or "Boot Sequence". There you need to update the order of the bootable mediums. Set the CD/DVD drive to have higher priority than the HDD. This will make the computer check the DVD for something bootable before it checks the HDD.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! It finally worked...I've been at this for hours!